# Stop plotting after certain timestamp

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Only trying to limit/stop a script after/before

a specific date and time

```
G2S = request.security('GOLD', 'D')    
G2S_ma = request.security('SILVER', 'D')    
spr = (G2S + G2S_ma) / 2    
if (time \< timestamp(2022, 04, 28,0,0,0))    
g = plot(spr,color=color.white,linewidth=1)
```

cannot figure it out..
'end of line without line continuation'.

Comment: You have multiple issues here, let's focus on the first. If you create a local scope (like IF, or FOR) the next line has to be __EXACTLY__ indented with 4 spaces or 1 tab. This is still not the full solution to your problem but I wanted to emphasize this as this is `Pineism` (meaning: the Pine devs could have found better way to solve this, but they chose this). Whenever you don't use the indentation described above, the interpreter will think that is a new line and handle it as that.

Answer (score 0):

Stopping plotting after a timestamp: Taking this by the word, you cannot stop plotting.

However you can modify the plotted line's transparency on every bar and you can make a plotted line invisible (the engine will still plot the line anyway although an optimizer might realize there is nothing to plot).

You will need to create a conditional which will be **TRUE** if you are within your expected time range and it will be **FALSE** if you are outside of that time range.

You also need to familiarize yourself with a conditional value assignment through a ternary operator:

```
color_variable = conditional ? value_when_true : value_when_false
```

Translated to more realistic example:

```
color_variable = conditional ? color.rgb(red, green, blue, transp) : color.rgb(red, green, blue, 100)
```

That **100** at the end of the color setting will set it to 100% transparent or invisible.

The ternary operator ensures that in every case you will set a value to the variable (`tl;dr` this is also connected to some `Pineism`) and it won't be left unset.

Final example:

```
color_variable = conditional ? color.rgb(red, green, blue, transp) : color.rgb(red, green, blue, 100)
plot(series = your_series, color = color_variable)
```

You can put all the code to the `plot` function but that would be harder to read:

```
plot(series = your_series, color = conditional ? color.rgb(red, green, blue, transp) : color.rgb(red, green, blue, 100) )
```